# Android - Where should we put the additional business logic in architecture?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mvvm, clean-architecture

All examples in Android architecture are about taking data over the Internet and saving it to the database. I know how to implement this architecture. But I couldn't figure out exactly where to put some events. Example:

- Getting camera permission
- Save the photo to the gallery.
- Turn off notifications

Which layer do these events belong to? Is it correct to use usecases as in the picture? There are many stages of saving the image to the gallery (permission, storage control, image extension ...). Does the UseCases class swell too much? Should one more layer be used here?

[image: UseCases]

Answer (score 0):

The UseCase in domain layer should have only business logic, when it needs to interact with the system (permissions, open settings, save to disk, etc.) it should execute a method of the interface. This interface is implemented in another layer, which is not domain and is framework specific.